# Is it possible to run .webtest files in VSTS Release Pipeline with VSTest task?

Tags: performance-testing, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, vstest

I am able to associate my webtest files to test cases in VSTS. I would like to be able to execute those webtests via the right-click->Run Test context menu in VSTS. I have defined a build pipeline and a release pipeline that theoretically should work, but the VSTest task is not finding my webtests.

I have verified the files are in the correct directory. In fact, I can make a build pipeline with the VSTest task set to find tests using "test assemblies". "Test Plan" or "Test Run" fail to find tests.

Because of my need to run these tests from the test hub interface, I'm not aware of any other release tasks that might accomplish what I need. Has anyone ever done this, or know what I might be doing wrong? Please let me know if additional information is needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your test project/solution is build with VS2017 or higher.

I got the same issue but I was using VS2015 for my test solution.
In build pipeline VSTtest task should be v2.0.